# CSS syntax meaning list style

Tags: html, css, syntax

I have that site code inside body

HTML:

```
<ul id="navlist">
    <li class="first">
        <a href="/" id="current">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/Store/">Store</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and this style CSS:

```
ul#navlist
{
    float: right;
}

ul#navlist li
{
    display: inline;
}

ul#navlist li a
{
    border-left: 1px dotted #8A8575;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: #8A8575;
    text-decoration: none;
    float: left;
}

ul#navlist li:first-child a
{
    border: none;
}

ul#navlist li a:hover
{
    color: #F6855E;
}
```

I try to understand what means and syntax is of:

```
ul#navlist li:first-child a

componentClass#class componentClass:class(???) componentClass
```

What is `first-child`? Is there a `second child`modificator? Are those css blocks are considered by logical alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`First-child` is first child of parent element - http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selectors/firstchild.html

In this case, `li:first-child` is the same as `li.first`.

For second child, you can use `li:nth-child(2)` (unsupported in IE <= 8), `li.first + li` or `:first-child + li` (in this case where we speak about `li`s) - siblings or **first** element. In this case you can use simplier `li + li` (all `li`s except the first one). Etc.

Look what options you have when you want to fire Xth element - http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selectors/#t50 (+ you can use siblings selector to fire `next` element (`+`), or `all next siblings` selector (`~`)), etc.

Comment: Last question `ul#navlist` is refering to id="navlist" if I want to refer to class it would be `ul.navlist`?

Comment: Yes, you're right. You can use shorter `#navlist` (or `.navlist` for class), it fires element with `id=navlist` but not necessarily `UL` (for example `<div id=navlist>`).